# How to find the url where login credentials are send to?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, ejs

Using PHP/cURL I'm trying to login to [www.teliatv.dk](http://teliatv.dk/) with my credentials and return some json from a file on the domain, while keeping the session alive by storing the session cookie in a txt file.

```
<?php
// Login to www.teliatv.dk
$username = "xxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init("http://www.teliatv.dk/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
echo curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Display content of cookie.txt
echo file_get_contents($file);

// Retrieve json content
$ch = curl_init("https://www.teliatv.dk/rest/secure/livechannels/2087/decryptionticket_postasget?deviceType=WEB&callback=jQuery161003904806077480316_1421055449439&_=1421055849886");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
echo curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

However, my script doesn't seem to be able to login to the site in the first place.

The action attribute in the login form on the site is empty and the HTTPheader doesn't reveal a URL when submitting the form.

Apparently the site uses [Embedded JavaScript](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) (EJS) so generate the HTML content of the site (which I'm unfamiliar with). I don't know if somehow this is the reason why I'm unable to find the URL where username and password is sent?

I hope somebody's able to help me out.

Comment: Network mode (or equivalent) in your favourite browser's debug tools should tell you exactly what requests your browser sends, and to which urls

Comment: if url in form is empty, then form is sending on current url (page, when form is located)

You need to set POST or GET data in your curl request. CURLOPT_USERPWD unsuitable for this

Comment: I've tried using:
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username_field=".$username."&password_field=".$password);` However, I don't know if this syntax with the form fields is correct. In any case, the result is still the same :(
**RESULT**: http://clubace.dk/teliatv.txt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're sending a GET request. Login stuff use POST requests most of the time.
You may also have a look at the answer from the server after your first request: it may contain an message or an error that could help you.

Good luck!